# Create S3 Bucket along with AMI installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

I'm planning to create a small public AMI for converting text files to PDF (I find nothing satisfying on the Store) and I have an issue.

I understood that AMI is nothing else than a frozen copy of a software that I've run successfully on another machine.

I however have an issue: how do I **create** a S3 Bucket **by the installation** of the AMI.

**Use case:**

- A user comes to the store and finds the idea of my service cool and launch an instance.
- The instance needs to create a S3 bucket to save the converted files (and maybe the source file as well) and it has to be one bucket per user and not a big bucket for all the files converted via the software.

**I have many questions for that**:

- Is that possible to achieve that (was it designed like this)?
- How should I create the bucket, is there a point and click interface at AMI setup or I need to do via AWS SDK?
- If I need to it via the SDK, is there a way to access the user credentials (or some random token) so that I can create a bucket successfully?
- Am I wrong, should be all the file saved on EBS and made available via an nginx on the AMI (and not using S3 at all)?

Oh and sorry if this question seems silly but I'm very fresh in this AWS cool tech!

Thanks!

Comment: so you created basically a service that convert text to pdf ? and want to make it available to others ? nice; lets say I want to use it, why would I need to launch an ec2 instance, create a s3 bucket etc just if I want to convert a text into pdf ? run the service yourself (api-gateway or ec2 instance or whatever way to host your service running) and just make it available so I can upload the text file and you convert it. You need 1 global s3 bucket with each customer with a folder and their files inside their folder

Comment: If some customers have privacy issue and want to run your service on their end (with their own instances) I would leave it to them to create themselves a s3 bucket and have some config files which will reference the s3 bucket to be used from the ec2 instance; just have some config guides for those customers who are willing to host the service from their end.

Comment: Merci @FrédéricHenri! Yeah that's probably what I'm gonna do (you can post it as answer the "runtime config file" solution). You have to imagine that in my case, we're talking about hundreds of docx,doc and odt which need to be converted and in some cases, user have thousands so it takes a bit of a place. I'll create an endpoint accepting a config file and upload to the according s3 bucket!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using AWS cloudformation.
Steps would be that you first create an AMI and then write a cloudformation script that

1. Creates an instance from that AMI
2. Creates the S3 buckets for the
3. Map the newly created EC2 with the S3. (Since S3 buckets names are unique globally you might not get the name you want) .

However note that the services in cloud are not installed for each customer like the traditional on-premise system.

Here you have a concept of tenants. So every new customer would be a tenant and should be served from the same infrastructure. Basically when a new customer comes in you onboard that as a tenant and possibly create a folder within the already created S3 for this tenant where you store its artifacts. Or if for some justified business reason you just want to have a separate S3 bucket for each of the tenant then even that new S3 bucket should be created during tenant onboarding. Store the mapping of the tenant and the S3 folder/bucket somewhere so that you know which tenant's artifacts to store where

Comment: Hey there, I really like your solution! It's probably the way to do. However I have a practical question: if I publish it on the store, can someone do a oneclick install with cloudformation? I want to create something simple and easy to use! :)

Comment: No, you will do the install via the cloudformation yourself only ONCE. After that somewhere on your site you should have the option for users to subscribe to your service. When they do that then you take the user's details and trigger an onboarding for that tenant from your endpoint

Comment: So if I follow you properly, it will not be possible to have this one click deployment from the AWS Market right? What a pity...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. AWS market place is not supposed to be for this use case. That is simply a place for AMIs. As a bad workaround, if you are hell bent on doing it that way, could be that in your AMI user data you put a 'aws s3 mb s3://mybucket' command with some random numbers after the bucket name. But I would strongly strongly discourage you from doing that. That's not what SAAS is all about

Comment: Yeah for sure, I'll prefer let a webinterface where people will be able to set their bucket, that seems way better :)